# Remove Active Element With JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add some validation on something I'm working on. Basically if no input is processed, it would return a red paragraph telling you to enter something and return false. The problem I'm having is how to remove it when a valid value is processed.

```
var input = document.getElementById('input'),
    button = document.getElementById('add')

function removeItem() {
    var item = this.parentNode
    var parent = item.parentNode
    parent.removeChild(item)

}

button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (input.value === '') {
        var p = document.querySelector('p')
        p.style.display = 'block'
        return false
    } else if (!input.value === '') {
        p.style.display = ''
        return true
    }

    var userInput = document.createTextNode(input.value)
    var li = document.createElement('li')
    var ul = document.getElementById('todo')

    var remove = document.createElement('button')
    remove.innerHTML = 'Remove'

    remove.addEventListener('click', removeItem);

    ul.insertBefore(li, ul.childNodes[0])
    li.appendChild(userInput)
    li.appendChild(remove)
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input"/>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<p>plz add</p>
<div class="container">
    <ul id="todo"></ul>
</div>
```

```css
p {
    display: none;
    color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: Indenting code properly can be helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- You `return` in both `if ... else` cases, which (if it would work) makes the rest of the code unreachable.
- The `else if` condition is unnecessary (since the `if` condition was already false), but is also wrong: `!` has precedence over `===`, so better use `!==`. Anyway, it is not needed at all.

Here is the corrected code:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input'),
    button = document.getElementById('add');

function removeItem() {  
    var item = this.parentNode;
    var parent = item.parentNode;
    parent.removeChild(item);
}

button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var p = document.querySelector('p');
    if (input.value.trim() === '') {
        p.style.display = 'block';
        return false;
    }
    p.style.display = '';

    var remove = document.createElement('button');
    remove.textContent = 'Remove';
    remove.addEventListener('click', removeItem);
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    li.appendChild(remove);
    todo.insertBefore(li, todo.childNodes[0]);
});
```

```css
p {
 display: none;
 color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input"/>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<p>plz add</p>
<div class="container">
    <ul id="todo"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time out of your day for this! :)

Answer (score 0):

add an id to the error element. Then :

```
var el = document.getElementById('theidyouset')
el.parentNode.removeChild( el );
```

or you could hide it

```
el.className += " classhiddenwithcss";
```

Comment: Rather than modifying the DOM every time the button is clicked, just show or hide it.

Comment: that is a good approach, I was just answering the exact question asked.

Comment: I've added the option to hide it to my answer.

Comment: also `el.remove()`

Comment: @GabrielPozo in the javascript logic

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS classes and simply add or remove the class from the class list as needed.

Also, because you are using `return` in both of your `if/else` cases, the code will stop processing and not continue on to do the rest of the work. Move the `if/else` to the end of the code so that `return` is the last thing you do.

And, use semi-colons at the end of your statements.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input'),
button = document.getElementById('add')

function removeItem() {
  
  var item = this.parentNode;
  var parent = item.parentNode;
  parent.removeChild(item);

}

button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
var p = document.querySelector('p') 
 
var userInput = document.createTextNode(input.value)
var li = document.createElement('li')
var ul = document.getElementById('todo')
  
var remove = document.createElement('button')
remove.innerHTML = 'Remove'

remove.addEventListener('click', removeItem);
  
ul.insertBefore(li, ul.childNodes[0])
li.appendChild(userInput)
li.appendChild(remove)

if (input.value === '') {
 p.classList.remove("hidden");
 return false;
} else  {
  p.classList.add("hidden");
  return true;
}

})
```

```css
p {
 color: #f00;
}

.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input"/>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<p class="hidden">plz add</p>
<div class="container">
<ul id="todo"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however the add button does not work.

Comment: @GabrielPozo That wasn't your question answer updated.